# How to read a csv file where each element is a list of numbers and the lists are of varying sizes?

Tags: python, list, csv, object, multidimensional-array

I have a csv file that looks like

| column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [2,3,4] | [3,4] | [5,3] |
| [3,4] | [4,2,3] | [2,4] |

I have the knowledge about the number of rows and columns but nothing about number of elements in a list. Ideally, I would like to save it in a numpy array of objects. If it's not possible to read such a file. I think I will try to save number of elements in a list, and store a single column of numbers, and then read that file into an array and do some reshaping. This won't be ideal as I will be saving the csv file a few times, but reading the files a lot.

I have tried the usual stuff like,

```
with open('output/output.csv') as f2:
    lines = (f2.read().splitlines())
```

The output is

```
['"[2, 3, 4]","[3, 4]","[4, 5]"', '"[1, 4, 4, 8]","[3, 5, 4]","[4, 5]"']
```

Comment: Have you tried pandas `pd.read_csv`?

Comment: nope. I was expecting to save it into a numpy array

Comment: It's *possible,* but whoever thought using CSV for this data was a good idea should have their head examined. Look into `ast.literal_eval` for parsing the data, and perhaps `json` for saving it in a less brain-damaged format. CSV is fine for two-dimensional data, but less ideal for, well, everything else.

Comment: It was my idea to save it in a csv file. Thanks for the suggestion